# Random number generator repeats output values

Tags: vb.net

I have created an array that stores a set of random numbers. The size of the array is input into the variable i through a text box, "TextBox1". The random number generator produces the name numbers after each time the program begins. I have included an example of 1 being input into the text box 10 times. The first five are displayed after the program is run once. The next five is after the program is run a second time. Thi first image is the source code, second is the first time the program is run, and the third image is the second time I ran the code.

[image: Source Code:]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please Do Not post code as an image. It should be copied and pasted and formatted as code with the { } button.

Answer (score 3):

The random number generator takes a seed, in your code the seed is `123456`. If you provide the same seed, the same sequence of random numbers will be generated. This is useful if you want to repeat a program run. However, if you want a different sequence, you have to provide a different seed each time you run your program. If you call the constructor like `new Random()`, the system will provide a default seed. This default seed is usually time-based, so you will most likely get a different sequence of random numbers at each run.